# How to prevent PHP SESSION closing when the page is refreshed?

Tags: php, session

I have created Signup and Login systems for my gallery website. When a user tries to login into system, their user and password and admin privilege is checked. If it was successful, the username is appeared on top left corner of the home page and Login turns to Logout. The problem is that when I refresh the page, the user is logged out.

login.php code:

```
<?php

session_start();

class User

{

    public function CheckUser()

    {

        require "../app/core/database.php";

        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

            $username = $_POST['username'];

            $password = $_POST['pass'];

            //to prevent sql injection

            $username = stripcslashes($username);

            $password = stripcslashes($password);

            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);

            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

            $sql2 = "SELECT 'admin' FROM signup";

            $log_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

            $count = mysqli_num_rows($log_result);

            if ($count == 1) {

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                $_SESSION['is_admin'] = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

                header("Location: ../home/index");

            } else {

                echo "<script>Invalid()</script>";

            }

        }

    }

}

?>

<script>

    function Invalid() {

        alert("Invalid user/password");

    }

</script>
```

a part of home page code (index.php):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

include "../app/model/loadImages.php";

include "../app/core/config.php";

include "../app/model/login.php";

?>

<body>
  <nav>
    <?php while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rows[] = $row ?>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><?php echo $row['header_1'] ?> <em><?php echo $row['header_2'] ?></em></a>
        <span style="font-weight: normal; color:white;">
          <label>
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
              echo $_SESSION['username'];
            } ?>
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      </nav>
 <section class="overlay-menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="main-menu">
          <ul>

            <li>
              <?php
              if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && !isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                echo "<a href='/MyProject/public/login/index.php'>LogIn</a>";
              } else {
                echo "<a href='' action='EndSession();'>Logout</a>";
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href='/MyProject/public/admin/index'>Admin Area</a>";
                echo "</li>";
              } ?>

            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blog.html">Blog Entries</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="single-post.html">Single Post</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
            <p><?php echo $row['message_1'] ?></p>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<script>
    function EndSession() {

      <?php session_unset(); ?>
    }
  </script>
```

index.php for login page:

```
<?php
include "../app/core/config.php";
include "../app/model/login.php";

$login = new User();
$login->CheckUser();

?>

<body>
    
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('../../app/views/login/images/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                        Login
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Username is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Type your password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31">
                        <a href="#">
                            Forgot password?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="txt1 text-center p-t-54 p-b-20">
                        <span>
                            Or Sign Up Using
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-c-m">
                        <a href="#" class="login100-social-item bg3">
                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-col-c p-t-155">
                        <span class="txt1 p-b-17">
                            Or Sign Up Using
                        </span>

                        <a href="<?php echo $root ?>/public/signup/index.php" class="txt2">
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it uses session from Login.php

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: FYI stripcslashes has nothing to do with sql injection and does not help to prevent it. All it will do in your case is potentially prevent a user from logging in by mangling their password

Comment: Anyway does your home page call session_start() anywhere?

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the CheckUser() function inside the User class?

Comment: It uses session from Login.php . If I add session_start() in index.php, it would give error and say: ignoring session_start() because it has already been started.

Comment: @C.Celora I added index.php for login page

Comment: I think it might be stupid, but i tryed the code on my pc. Is it possible that the session is working fine, but you are printing it inside a **<span>** with **color:white** inside it's style? What color is the page background?

Comment: Also i was checking the home/index.php and you never close the bracket of the while loop. Probably you copyied only a part of the code, but you never know :)

Comment: @C.Celora the background is grey. This code works fine but refreshing the page make the user to logout.

Comment: Is there a **session_destroy** somewhere in the code? maybe in the included files

Comment: @C.Celora yes, I updated my home page code. I have used javascript for unsetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated the problem. The **session_unset** inside the js function is called when you refresh the page, besides it is inside a JS function.

Remove that funciton, than create a new file called logout.php:

```
<?php 
session_unset();
header("Location: ../home/index.php");
?>
```

Modify the **a** tag inside home/index.php:

```
<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

Side note: consider using [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) instead of session_unset() for the logout

Answer (score 0):

You have to create session and setcookie , this method i hope helps you

First select validate the user :
The password_verify funnction works if you store the password with bcrypt algorithm

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
        $u = $dbmysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $p = $_POST['p'];



        $sql = $dbmysqli->prepare('SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?');
        $sql->bind_param("s", $u);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->store_result();
    }
    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
        $sql->bind_result($db_id, $db_username, $db_pass_str);
        $sql->fetch();
        if (password_verify($p, $db_pass_str)) {
            // Verification success! User has logged-in!
            // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime('+30 days'), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime('+30 days'), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime('+30 days'), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        } else {
            // Incorrect password
            echo 'login_failed';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Then you have to create a check login status file.php like this (include this in every page if you want user stay logged in) :

```
<?php
$user_ok = FALSE;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";

function evalLoggedUser($dbmysqli,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = $dbmysqli->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = ? AND uname = ? AND pswd = ?');
    $sql->bind_param("sss", $id,$u,$p);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    $numrows = $sql->num_rows;
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
    //$log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9$./]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);

    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($dbmysqli,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['pass'];
    //$_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9$./]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
    $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];

    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($dbmysqli,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    if ($user_ok == TRUE);
}
?>
```

And finally the logout.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])) {
    setcookie("id", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("user", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("pass", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
}
session_destroy();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location: message.php?msg=Error:_Logout_Failed");
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not recommend people to store credentials in cookies! Anyone with access to the users computer would then have access to the users credentials as well! _Never_ store  sensitive info in the client! You shouldn't need to store the credentials in the session either.